# Implementing complex TreeList structure

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-treelist

I'll need to use correct component to implement this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImENk.jpg . I'm currently looking at TreeList Examples ( https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/remote-data-binding ) using json data from server. Can you give some advice on creating this treelist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a PoC once for a similar scenario like yours. I've simulated a TreeList with a Grid, and it worked:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.917/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.917/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.917/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.917/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .item-level {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 10px;
    }
    .level-arrow-expanded:before {
      content: "\00bb"
    }
    .level-arrow-collapsed:before {
      content: "\00ab"
    }
    .item-cell {
      cursor: pointer
    }
 td[role="gridcell"] {
  padding: 0;
 }
 .cell-container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 6.4px;
  padding-left: 9.6px;
  padding-right: 9.6px; 
  padding-top: 6.4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .header-container {
  padding: 0
 }
 .header-editable-cell {
  color: #9cc3e5; 
  font-weight: bold
 }
 .k-grid tr:hover td .cell-container {
  background-color: #bdb4af !important
 }
  </style>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.917/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.917/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.917/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  
  <script id="line-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
 <div class='cell-container'>
  <div class='item-level #= (data.Level < 4 ? "level-arrow-" + (data.Collapsed ? "collapsed" : "expanded") : "") #'></div>
  # for (let i = -1; i < (data.Level - 1); i++) { #
   <div class='item-level level-space'></div>
  # } #    
  #= data.Line #
 </div>
  </script>
  
  <script>
   $(function() {
      const lineTemplate = $("#line-template").html();
      
      let data = [];
      
      let cols = [{
        title: "&nbsp;",
        field: "Line",
        locked: true,
        width: 200,
        template: lineTemplate,
        attributes: { "class": "item-cell" }
      }, {
        title: "Customer Type",
        field: "CustomerType",
        width: 300
      }];
      
      for (var n = 0; n < 50000; n++) {
        let level = (n % 5),
            dataItem = {
              Line: n,
              CustomerType: (n % 2 == 0 ? "All" : "3rd Party"), 
              Level: level,
              Show: true,
              Index: n,
              Collapsed: false
             };
        
        data.push(dataItem);
      }
      
      let grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
          data: data,
          pageSize: 20,
          filter: { field: "Show", operator: "eq", value: true }
        },
        height: 500,
        columns: cols,
        scrollable: {
          virtual: true
        }
      }).data("kendoGrid");
      
      grid.lockedTable.on("click", "td.item-cell", function() {
        let data = grid.dataSource.data(),
            dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr")),
            item;
        
        for (let i = 0, count = data.length; i < count; i++) {
          item = data[i];
          
          if (item.Index == dataItem.Index) {
            dataItem.Collapsed = !dataItem.Collapsed;
          }
          else if (item.Index > dataItem.Index) {
            if (dataItem.Index != i && item.Level == 0) {
              break;
            }
            
            item.Show = !dataItem.Collapsed;
          }
        }
        
        grid.dataSource.fetch();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo in Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/ugUbAXuT/2)

Why I did that? To work with huge datasets which I don't know if is your case tho. As you can see, the above *TreeList* is displaying 50k rows, virtualized. The problem is that TreeList does not virtualizes([check out it's docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treelist)), but [Grid does](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/scrollable.virtual).

How that works:

1. Lock the first column to be the collpase/expand column. You can also lock more columns;
2. In your dataItems(row's data), you have to use some control properties, which are: `Collapsed`, `Level`, `Show` and `Index`. They control the collpase/expand behaviour and the hierarchical display. Add a `console.log(data)` before Grid's initialization to checkout how it's been filled;
3. The `Show` property handles the collpase/expand displaying status. Once a row is `Show = false`, it will be hidden. That works because of a filter in the dataSource: `filter: { field: "Show", operator: "eq", value: true }`;
4. A click event on the `item-cell` class manages the row's children display status. That class is added in the first column as: `attributes: { "class": "item-cell" }`. The event changes the `Show` property for the children rows;
5. The template `line-template` will display the right level indetation and the arrows for the collpase/expand column;

Comment: I tried simulating the same implementation, fetching a dataSource from server, but the click event stopped working correctly. Can you take a look? https://dojo.telerik.com/ugUbAXuT/3

Comment: @JordanMichael as you modified the dataSource, you forgot to keep the filtering settings, which handles collpase/expand feature. Check it out: https://dojo.telerik.com/ugUbAXuT/4